# How to show a dialog activity over another dialog activity in android 4.4.2?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, themes

I have a theme to show my activities as dialogs, making the window background translucent and dim, and no window title, and etc. all these items are essential for my activities appearance. The problem is when i need to show an activity that describes some aspects form another activity in the background, the result is just an activity shown at the time. 
**Each activity in my app has the same dialog theme, when i start an activity B from and activity A, the activity A hides and activity B shows, when the activity B should show over the activity A due to the dialog theme. This occur only in android 4.4.2.**
I have tested diferents combinations of the items in the theme declaration but nothing changed, even i have tried with the intents flags when i start the activity B, making the intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, and others i believe could work but nothing again.
In one the test that i have made, if the activity B is started from an activity A, but the activity A is not a dialog activity then the activity B shows fine over the activity A. My problem is how to start dialog activities  form another dialog activities without hiding.

My dialog theme decalration:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Every activity declaration in the manifiest has this theme in the android:theme.

Thanks in advance, and sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved my problem...
As i said in the question above, if the activity B is started from an activity A, but the activity A is not a dialog activity, then the activity B shows fine over the activity A. So i did a search in the @android:style/Theme.*, to find one that allows me to show an activity as a dialog without be a real dialog theme, and then apply this theme to my launch activity and all the remaining activities form here will be shown fine with my DialogStyle. So this is the theme that i found:

```
<style name="CompatibleDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item> 
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.InputMethod</item>
</style>
```